# iterate through slices of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dim1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'dim2': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y'], 'val': [2, 4, 6, 8]})
```

This can represent an array of N dimensions, I have chosen two here for simplicity. I will convert this to a numpy array and then want to iterate and sum over this numpy array for each 'slice' of the array. I have achieved this but I do not know how to generalise for N dimensions.

Function to convert to df -> numpy.array

```
def df_to_numpy(df: pd.DataFrame) -> np.array:
    # Function to convert to np.array
    try:
        shape = [len(level) for level in df.index.levels]
    except AttributeError:
        shape = [len(df.index)]
    ncol = df.shape[-1]
    if ncol > 1:
        shape.append(ncol)
    return df.to_numpy().reshape(shape)
```

Now to convert use this and unstack(). (Not generalise yet due to column names but easy enough to at later point)

```
arr = df_to_numpy(df.set_index(['dim1', 'dim2']).unstack())
```

Now use a loop and swapaxes() to iterate through the slices of this array

```
for _ in range(len(arr.shape)):
    # we now iterate through the unique groupings of this dimension
    for ii in range(arr.shape[0]):
        print('Unq grouping no.: ',ii)
        print('Sum: ', arr[ii,:].sum())
    # swap the last and first axes and repeat step
    arr = arr.swapaxes(0,len(arr.shape) - 1)
```

This appears to work for my example and some higher dimension ones I've tried. However this is not generalisable. e.g. for 4 dimensions the sum would be arr[ii,:,:,:], how can I generalise this line to work for n dimensions?

Comment: I think I have answered it, simply use the elipse operator `arr[...,ii]`

Answer (score 0):

looking to your data frame it feels like your headers are misleading. the dimesion is x and y. In this case you have unorganized data set. So if you want to have 4 dimensional you can still keep structure of your data frame just have extra 2 rows for each a and b. like now you have a: x, y. Then you can have a: x, y, z, k.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dim1': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 'dim2': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'k', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'k'], 'val': [2, 4, 6, 8, 3, 2, 1, 5]})

def df_to_numpy(df: pd.DataFrame) -> np.array:
    # Function to convert to np.array
    try:
        shape = [len(level) for level in df.index.levels]
    except AttributeError:
        shape = [len(df.index)]
    ncol = df.shape[-1]
    if ncol > 1:
        shape.append(ncol)
    return df.to_numpy().reshape(shape)

arr = df_to_numpy(df.set_index(['dim1', 'dim2']).unstack())
arr
for _ in range(len(arr.shape)):
    # we now iterate through the unique groupings of this dimension
    for ii in range(arr.shape[0]):
        print('Unq grouping no.: ',ii)
        print('Sum: ', arr[ii,:].sum())
    # swap the last and first axes and repeat step
    arr = arr.swapaxes(0,len(arr.shape) - 1)
```

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your point. The inputs here will be a single table will always be of that format. An example of a 3D version would be `pd.DataFrame({'dim1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'dim2': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y'], 'dim3': ['i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'j', 'j', 'j', 'j'], 'val': [2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7]})`

Comment: After reading your edit I think I understand. It looks like adding `k` and `z` here (rather than in a new dimension) would achieve the same result. However, ultimately I will multiply each dimension (in order) by a factor that is based off these sums. If we add `k` and `z` here we won't achieve the same result.

Comment: from your initial datframe it felt like a and b are points and x, y is there coordinates. x would represent in my mind 1 dimesnsion and y the second. the examaple for 3d that you give doesnot seem to me as 3d. my version for 4d is unonrganized but if you want to have 3d organized (voxel) the then your structure does not look correct. Hope you will solve it:)